# Can't able to see Changes Branches Pull Request Sync even after connect to project in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, source-control-explorer

I Can't able to see Changes Branches Pull Request Sync even after connect to project in Azure DevOps.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDaFa.png)

Answer (score 2):

You are using new Git user experience. If you want to use version control and repository in team explorer, please follow the steps:

1.Open tools->options:

[image]

2.Disable `New Git user experience` option:
[image]

3.Result:

[image]

Comment: @Ashok Glad to hear that! Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) which will also help others in the community.